# difference between onClickListener and onItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-listview

what is the difference between onClickListener and onItemClickListener in Android ListViews ?
And what are the different implementations of these ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ListView has an Item Click listener for each row of the listview but the onClickListener is for the whole listview no matter which ever row you click the *onClick* and *onItemClickListener* is called but the values that come with each method are different.

[OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) you can use for lets say going to a particular activity when a particular row is touched.

[OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) you can check if the listview has received a touch by the user so do you want to refresh the list? or change the scrollbar's view or do something with the listview as a whole unit.

Comment: what is the difference between implementing an onItemClickListener for a listview and an onClickListener for each row of the listView? Does it have any performance issues or does it not even matter which strategy, although the onItemClickListener one is nicer, I choose?