# Android: Click outside of a listview in a listfragment

Tags: java, android, listview, onclicklistener

I have a listview which occupies all the space of the layout IN THEORY, but actually it occupies only half of the layout because it has got only 5 elements and it doesn't cover all the screen. I'd like to know when I touch OUTSIDE of the listview. I tried to create a clicklistener method for the layout of the listfragment which contains the list, but it is never used because IN THEORY the listview occupies all the layout, so the click isn't found. It is the same for the layout of the activity more or less. In that case the click is found only on the edges, so I can't find a method to solve my problem.

Here is the fragment layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/list" />
```

Here is the activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.utente.actionbar.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:text="MULTI"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:text="SINGOLO"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />
```

Comment: @PavneetSingh No, it doesn't work

Comment: You want two part in your fragment first part is listview and the second one is out and below of the listview. And You want the second one is clickable? Is it right?

Comment: @mismanc Yes, but there aren't two layouts which divide the screen, there is a listview which occupies all the screen in theory, but it occupies only an half concretely because there are only 5 fragments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IN THEORY the listview occupies all the layout

Not a theory, that is exactly what happens; by using `android:layout_height="match_parent"` the View will always take the full screen height.

`listView.setOnClickListener` would work if you want to see if you clicked *anywhere* in the `ListView`, **but** you typically would instead want `listView.setOnItemClickListener` to see if you have clicked on any single item, and not the entire list.

Refer: [difference between onClickListener and onItemClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044447/difference-between-onclicklistener-and-onitemclicklistener)

If you really want to shrink the `ListView`, then `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` is an option, but I'm not sure that works without content actually being loaded into that View since the content wrapping is applied *at inflation-time*, which since it has no adapter set, can't be done.

---

If you are needing to detect a listener literally "outside the ListView", then you need to set some type of click / touch listener on the `rootView` of that Fragment.

```
public View onCreateView(...) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(...);

    listView = ...;
    listView.setOnTouchListner(...
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return false; // Says that click was not handled here. 
        }
    });

    rootView.setOnTouchListner(...
        // TODO: Check if click landed outside the ListView
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (v.getId() != android.R.id.listView) { // Not the list
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    // Up action more reliable than "down"

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    );
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand how I can find the outside click

Comment: `listView.setOnClickListener` will capture the entire View. It's your task to decide if you clicked on an item in the list or not

Comment: But if I use `listView.setOnClickListener` I find the click inside the list, I'd like to know when I click outside of the list

Comment: No, you are confusing a **onClick** with an **onItemClick**. The later only gets caught inside the list

Comment: Yes I know the difference, maybe I didn't explain myself. I have a listview and I want to know when I click outside of that, in the rest of the layout. The methods which you told me say when I click on the listView (on the item or in general on the view), so I don't have to use them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137896/discussion-between-curio-and-cricket-007).

Comment: `setOnClickListener` on the root layout then? You can set a click listener on any `View` class.

Comment: I tried setOnClickListener on the layout, but it is covered by the listview so the click isn't found

Comment: And you also tried `wrap_content` on the ListView with that strategy?

Comment: 1)How can I check if the click landed outside of the listview?(you wrote it as a comment in the code) 2)It doesn't work if I call the listener on the view of the fragment

Comment: Well, that was just the idea ;) I don't "know how". On second thought, setting on `onTouchListener` makes more sense.

Comment: It should as soon as you don't make `match_parent` on the ListView

Comment: I put wrap_content both on ListView and on the Layout

Comment: You want `match_parent` on the outer layout. Otherwise you have the same problem that the outer layout has the same boundaries as the ListView and no touches can be detected there

Comment: YES, I put match_parent to the outer layout and it works! However I didn't understand why, can you explain it to me?

Comment: I just did. `match_parent` on the outer layout is the whole screen. (Or for Fragments, whatever container they are in). When you set `wrap_content`, you "shrink wrap" the view to anything that is displayed within it.

Comment: aaah I understood, many thanks! I didn't use the code which you post now, but the previous, but they are the same more or less

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- Or specific height -->
    android:id="@android:id/list" />

<View 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/clickView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In Fragmet

```
public View onCreateView(...) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(...);
    View clickView = rootView.findViewById(...);
    clickView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Do something here
    }
});


    return rootView;
}
```

I guess this solves your problem.

Comment: An explicit empty view should work. Didn't cross my mind :)

Comment: I do like this solution better, though, though it is not exactly "outside the ListView", it's just "some other view"